# Tomcat 7 Web Application stops processing requests

Tags: java, tomcat

We are using tomcat 7.0.19, for a jsf(richfaces),seam, jpa web application.

We have noticed after about 2 months, the web requests stop being processed.

We are using HTTP/1.1 Connector. The heap and permgen memory seem fine. There is no out of memory errors in the logs.
We have used jvisualvm to monitor heap, permgen, threads and thread dump, AND THEY ALL LOOK OK.

The localhost_access_log stops being updated. The connector port is still listening.

After we restart Tomcat, the new requests are fine.

Can you please advise other areas we should look into for investigation (any additional tracing). Should we configure Request Dumper Filter.

Should we upgrade to tomcat 7.0.29? What could cause the Connector to stop proccessing requests on the port?

Further info: Heap(1/6th used), PermGen(1/2 used). GC is effectively reducing the heap. The fact that local access log is not being updated, suggests the request is not making to the Servlet container. We are using JPA Connection Pool, have not noticed any db connection issues. After the restart, everything works well.

Thanks in advance.
B

Comment: Since your using JPA, you're web app probably connects to the database. Have you checked that the connection pool has still connections available?

Comment: What about garbage collection?  Does it come back or just stop working forever until restart?

Comment: Did you try to run it in debug mode?

Comment: Further info: Heap(1/6th used), PermGen(1/2 used). GC is effectively reducing the heap. The fact that local access log is not being updated, suggests the request is not making to the Servlet container. We are using JPA Connection Pool, have not noticed any db connection issues. After the restart, everything works well. Thanks, B.

Comment: check also the system log to see if there are problems with the network (card) that serves incoming requests.

Comment: Could this be related to any BIO Connector issues? We are using a Sun Solaris machine with SSL and default keep alive requests. Should we switch to NIO?

Comment: we are facing the same problem with Glassfish on Solaris 10. In our case the Glassfish dies (glassfish process is not visible in process list) suddenly without any warning or log.

Comment: This looks like an issue with tomcat 7:   http://www.tomcatexpert.com/ask-the-experts/tomcat-hangs-production-and-doesn%E2%80%99t-respond-new-http-requests

Apache bug link #  https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53173

Answer (score 1):

An issue with tomcat 7: tomcatexpert.com/ask-the-experts/… Apache bug [link](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53173) #

1. Upgrade to tomcat 7.0.32
2. Use NIO instead of BIO Connector.